# How can I add aunthentication system in R shiny application which I have created using goleum package?

Tags: r

I have tried polished but it doesn't respond to my application. In app_ui.R I added polished::secure_ui(app_ui) and in app_server.R i have added polished::secure_server(app_server) and also I have created the global.R file inside R and imported all the library and written this code polished::global_sessions_config(
app_name = "my_shiny_apps",
api_key = "*********************"
)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using polished with golem: https://github.com/Tychobra/polished_example_apps/tree/master/08_golem_app

Be sure to check out the changes made to the run_app() function here: https://github.com/Tychobra/polished_example_apps/tree/master/08_golem_app/R/run_app.R